# Can I put two update statements for the same table in a condition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have two update statement blocks. Both for the same table with different 'where' part. I want that if one update runs, the other shouldn't.

Here's my code for the update statements:

```
Update transactionalData.TBL_WORK_ORDER_BOOKING_DETAILS  
 set Status='COMPLETED',EndDate= @date,Hours= convert (float,datediff(ss,StartDate,  @date ))/3600  
  where SignumID=@signumID and BookingID=@BookingID and status='started'  

Update transactionalData.TBL_WORK_ORDER_BOOKING_DETAILS
    set Status='Inprogress' where SignumID=@signumID and Status='onhold'  and BookingID=@BookingID
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Row Count to determine if the statement affected any rows.  Something like this...

```
Update transactionalData.TBL_WORK_ORDER_BOOKING_DETAILS  
 set Status='COMPLETED',EndDate= @date,Hours= convert (float,datediff(ss,StartDate,  @date ))/3600  
  where SignumID=@signumID and BookingID=@BookingID and status='started'  

If @@RowCount = 0
    Begin
        Update transactionalData.TBL_WORK_ORDER_BOOKING_DETAILS
        set Status='Inprogress' where SignumID=@signumID and Status='onhold'  and BookingID=@BookingID
    End
```